# operator and operand don't agree [equality type required]

Tags: sml, ml

This function calculate count element y in list

```
fun func y xs=List.length(List.filter(fn x => x=y) xs);

val countElement = fn : ''a -> ''a ?.list -> int
func 1 [1,2,3,4];
val it = 1 : int
```

But, when I write func 1.1 [1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1]; I get error:

```
stdIn:64.1-64.35 Error: operator and operand don't agree [equality type required]
operator domain: ''Z
operand:         real
in expression:
countElement 1.1
```

How can I solve it problem ?

Answer (score 3):

`real` is not an equality type in SML 97. That means you cannot use `=` to compare two `real`s.

Comment: How can I check if generic list have duplicate elements  in ml ?

Comment: @alex: You can't. If you cannot see if two elements are equal, you can't know if you have a duplicate or not, by definition.

Comment: all elements are equal type. For example [1.0,1.0,2.0] return true

Answer (score 2):

Standard ML has a concept of "equality types", or types that "admit equality"; or, more to the point, it has a concept of types that do *not* admit equality. You can only use `=` on types that *do* admit equality. (This is why its type is `''a * ''a -> bool` rather than `'a * 'a -> bool`. Type variables that start with `''` can only be instantiated to equality types.)

In SML '97, `real` is one type that does *not* admit equality; so, the following code will not type-check:

```
val oneIsOne = (1.0 = 1.0)    (* FAIL! *)
```

The reason for this design decision is that IEEE 754 (the standard that defines floating-point numbers) defines "equality" in a rather strange way — `NaN` is not equal to itself, and `0.0` is equal to `~0.0` even though `1 / 0.0` is not equal to `1 / ~0.0`. The language designers decided that they didn't want `=` to differ from the semantics specified by IEEE 754, but that they also didn't want the semantics of `=` to be different for `real` than for all other types in the language. Instead, they completely eliminated `=` for `real`, and made the IEEE 754 definition semantics available as `Real.==` [[link](http://sml-family.org/Basis/real.html#SIG:REAL.==:VAL)]. So, you can write:

```
fun countRealElement y xs = List.length (List.filter (fn x => Real.== (x,y)) xs)

val it = countRealElement 1.1 [1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1]    (* 1 *)
```

(where `countRealElement` has type `real -> real list -> int`).

Comment: How can I check if type is real ? I need that work for all types

Comment: `real` means, floating-point numbers; examples include `1.1`, `1.0`, `~1.0`, and `1e8`. You *cannot* make this work for all types; the best you can do is create a function `fun countMatchingElements f y xs = List.length (List.filter (fn x => f (x,y)) xs)`, such that (for example) `countMatchingElements op= 1 [1,2,3,4]` is `1`, as is `countMatchingElements Real.== 1.1 [1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1]`.

Comment: How can I identify type(int or real) in Run Time ?

Comment: By using an algebraic datatype as a wrapper; for example, `datatype intOrReal = Int of int | Real of real`. (There's no reflection in Standard ML; all typing is static/compile-time typing.)